Northern latitudes stretch vertically when generating tiles for Leaflet
I'm slicing a large image in QGIS. The image looks great in QGIS.

This is a piece of the Greenland playing field. (This is the playing field for the game, each square is a region that the player can interact with)
When I slice these images into pieces (I tried QTiles and QMetaTiles), the resulting images stretch closer to the northern and southern latitudes.

I understand that this is due to the fact that the planet is spherical. I'd like to find a way that just cuts my big picture into a lot of small ones. Without distortion.
CRS: WGS84

This seems a Projections 101 issue. The planet isn't spherical, it's spheroidal, and the projection in use isn't WGS84 geographic, but Web Mercator, which distorts distances  infinitely at the poles (so doesn't try to get that close). You probably should start over, using a projection you can live with (which will have distortion, but not as much as Web Mercator).
